# Which format of SUPEE 5994 for version 1.4.2.

Tags: patches

Has anyone successfully applied the patched SUPEE 5994 on version CE 1.4.2 this version appears to be not be addressed in the patch download options. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just now successfully patched a 1.4.2 using the 1.4.1.0-1.4.1.1 patch.  Everything seems to work fine.

A quick `find . -mtime 0` shows that it updated these files:

> ./lib/Varien/Io/File.php
>   ./lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
>   ./lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php
>   ./app/etc/applied.patches.list
>   ./app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
>   ./app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser
>   ./app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
>   ./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
>   ./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
>   ./app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
>   ./app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
>   ./app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php